# Scan text file for words with specific characters

Tags: regex, ruby, string

I tried to scan a text file for words that start with text such as `"aa123 "`, `"aa2545646"`, `"aa31151"`. `"aa"` is common for all words, and I want to get the words that start with `"aa"`. How can I do this?

I have tried this code:

```
input = "aa"
data = File.read(filepath).scan /\b#{input}/
```

**Updated:**

Now I need to get the words that start with `"bb"` and also starts with `"aa"` in single file how can I do this??

I have tried this code:

```
 input = "aa|bb"
 data = File.read(filepath).scan /\b#{input}.*?\b/
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using this regex: `.scan(/\b#{input}.*?\b/)`.

`String#scan` returns matched substrings so you need whole words to match.

Comment: `/\b#{input}.*?\b/` looks more natural; `\w` is kinda redundant.